# Understanding if the following subsets of a vector space satisfy addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Here, I'm supposed to justify if the following subsets are closed under scalar multiplication, addition, both or neither.

a) $W_1=\mathcal{S},Z_1=\{s \in\mathcal{S}|s \text{ is monotone}\}.$ Here, monotone sequences are defined as $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$ for all $n\geq 0$ or $a_{n+1} \leq a_n$ for all $n\geq 0$ for some sequence $(a_n)_n$.

b) $W_2=M_3(\mathbb{R}),Z_2=\{A \in M_3(\mathbb{R})|Tr(A)^3=Det(A) \}$.

a) I could pick $a_n=(0,1,1,...)$ and $b_n=(0,0,-1,-1,...)$ for some $a_n$, $b_n$ in $Z_1$ since this gives $(0,1,0,0,...)$ which isn't monotonic. Addition fails. I think multiplication will work though but I am not sure how to show this.

b) I'm almost certain addition fails but I am not so sure about scalar multiplication.

If someone could help me out, that would be great!

Comment: It seems like you're really on the right track, what exactly are you confused about?

Comment: It's the counter examples. I am not sure about the multiplication for the first one about how to show if that works or not.

For the second one I'm not sure how to show that multiplication by a scalar fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part $a)$ scalar multiplication, let $(a_n)$ be a monotone sequence and $s$ be a scalar. Then $s(a_n) = (s\cdot a_n)$ is also montone, since you can always just cancel from both sides of the $\leq$ sign.

For $b)$, consider

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
2&0&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix},B = \begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that $A$ and $B$ have determinant and trace $0$ so they are in $Z_2$, but $A+B$ has trace $8$ and determinant $8$, but obviously $8^3 \neq 8$.

For scalar multiplication we don't have closure either. Consider the identity matrix $I$. It has cubed trace and determinant $1$, so it is in $Z_2$, however if for example we multiply the matrix by $2$, we get a trace of $8$ and a determinant of $8$ and as noted about $8^3 \neq 8$.

Comment: Yup! I got that much figured out now. Thanks! What about the scalar multiplication for part b though? I think that WOULD work since I can can pull a constant out from the trace and determinant and they would just cancel. Is that the right idea?

Comment: @FutureMathperson as it turns out, that doesn't quite work (and one needs to be careful as with non upper triangular matrices the determinant formula is a little messier). I added some exposition about the failure of closure of s.m. in $Z_2$ to my answer.